# LAN PC with same IP than WAN IP

Tags: networking, router, ip

**Background**

After reading about network ranges recommended for private and public networks both in [random pages](https://ipwithease.com/public-ip-vs-private-ip/), and the [RFC 1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) I was wondering whether it would be much of a mess when a private lan PC has the same IP than a random public IP.

One problem is that the WAN IP address wouldn't be reachable, but maybe there are more reasons behind.

Obviously, the LAN IP won't be visible on the WAN.

**Question**

Would we have communication problem if a computer on the LAN has the same IP than a computer on the WAN? (Being for example, that we configure a lan network on 191.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Comment: Would those be your own addresses, or would you be "borrowing" some at random? Would the address range remain unique, or are you planning to use the same address in two places at once?

Comment: @user1686 I set up a network with a dhcp that delivers addresses in some range, say 191.1.0.0 - 191.1.255.255

Comment: Why would you use a non-private address range for a LAN? Why not use 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x?

Comment: @Minsky: Yes but that's not what I asked about...

Comment: If it doesn’t really matter, why ask this question?

Comment: The fact is, you would not be able to communicate with the corresponding 191.x.x.x address range on the WAN.

Comment: I think you need to clarify why you want to do this. Otherwise, this is a pointless discussion and you will in all probability be better of using a private address range.

Comment: @Minsky Using non-[RFC1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) addresses on a LAN is not recommended for a wide variety of reasons that can be found via a search engine. Could you use non-RFC1918 addresses, sure, but it creates a whole host of network issues, being why RFC1918 was created and why RFC1918 subnets are not allowed to be used in WAN.

Comment: Why would using domain names make a difference?

Comment: @Minsky Domain names have to be linked to an IP, else there's no route to the host.

Comment: Your question has already been answered. You will not be able to communicate with the corresponding IP addresses on the WAN. However, you have still not made clear WHY you think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you own the address range, and it is globally routed to your network, then you can do whatever you want with it. The distinction between "WAN" and "LAN" is fairly thin.

If you're using addresses that are *not* yours, it will work to some extent, but can definitely cause a few problems... but only for you, and not for the legitimate owner of those addresses.

> maybe once the request leaves the network it would actually get to the host?

It *might* – assuming your ISP doesn't do any spoofing protection. (And many do, because address spoofing is very commonly done to perform DDoS attacks, so an ISP would definitely pay attention to it.)

But even if it gets to the host, you have another problem: the host will not be able to send *any* replies back. (Whenever it tries to reply, it'll end up talking to the *real* owner of those addresses, who will reset the connection as unknown.)

So in other words, trying to use someone else's addresses in your LAN won't make them "public" addresses (the Internet isn't going to send you packets meant for them) – if you want to interact with the Internet, you will *still* need a NAT and a legitimate WAN address. So you don't gain anything by using them.

And because the addresses aren't from a private range, your games and apps might think that those *are* their public addresses (even though they aren't) and that you are not behind a NAT (even though you are). This might prevent online games or P2P software from working.

Finally, using someone else's addresses on your own machines will mean that they'll become unable to reach the *real* hosts which own those addresses. For example, if you configure your LAN to be 8.8.8.0/24, now you cannot talk to Google Public DNS anymore.

Comment: thanks for answering